# base recalibrator --known-sites argument does not work

Tags: java, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-20.04, vcf-variant-call-format, gatk

When I run this

```
gatk BaseRecalibrator -I ${aligned_reads}/file_copy_sorted.bam -R ${referance} --known-sites ${Known_Sites} -O ${data1}/sorted_Read1.table
```

this error occur

> A USER ERROR has occurred: Argument known-sites was missing: *Argument 'known-sites' is required*

this is what I tried

Using GATK jar /home/hi/Documents/gatk-4.4.0.0/gatk-package-4.4.0.0-local.jar
Running:
java -Dsamjdk.use_async_io_read_samtools=false -Dsamjdk.use_async_io_write_samtools=true -Dsamjdk.use_async_io_write_tribble=false -Dsamjdk.compression_level=2 -jar /home/hi/Documents/gatk-4.4.0.0/gatk-package-4.4.0.0-local.jar BaseRecalibrator -I /file_copy_sorted.bam -R --known-sites -O /sorted_Read1.table
USAGE: BaseRecalibrator [arguments]

First pass of the Base Quality Score Recalibration (BQSR) -- Generates recalibration table based on various
user-specified covariates (such as read group, reported quality score, machine cycle, and nucleotide context).
Version:4.4.0.0

Required Arguments:

--input,-I          BAM/SAM/CRAM file containing reads  This argument must be specified at least once.
Required.

--known-sites   One or more databases of known polymorphic sites used to exclude regions around known
polymorphisms from analysis.  This argument must be specified at least once. Required.

--output,-O         The output recalibration table file to create  Required.

--reference,-R      Reference sequence file  Required.

Optional Arguments:

--add-output-sam-program-record 
If true, adds a PG tag to created SAM/BAM/CRAM files.  Default value: true. Possible
values: {true, false}

--add-output-vcf-command-line 
If true, adds a command line header line to created VCF files.  Default value: true.
Possible values: {true, false}

--arguments_file        read one or more arguments files and add them to the command line  This argument may be
specified 0 or more times. Default value: null.

--binary-tag-name     the binary tag covariate name if using it  Default value: null.

--bqsr-baq-gap-open-penalty 
BQSR BAQ gap open penalty (Phred Scaled).  Default value is 40.  30 is perhaps better for
whole genome call sets  Default value: 40.0.

--cloud-index-prefetch-buffer,-CIPB 
Size of the cloud-only prefetch buffer (in MB; 0 to disable). Defaults to
cloudPrefetchBuffer if unset.  Default value: -1.

--cloud-prefetch-buffer,-CPB 
Size of the cloud-only prefetch buffer (in MB; 0 to disable).  Default value: 40.

--create-output-bam-index,-OBI 
If true, create a BAM/CRAM index when writing a coordinate-sorted BAM/CRAM file.  Default
value: true. Possible values: {true, false}

--create-output-bam-md5,-OBM 
If true, create a MD5 digest for any BAM/SAM/CRAM file created  Default value: false.
Possible values: {true, false}

--create-output-variant-index,-OVI 
If true, create a VCF index when writing a coordinate-sorted VCF file.  Default value:
true. Possible values: {true, false}

--create-output-variant-md5,-OVM 
If true, create a a MD5 digest any VCF file created.  Default value: false. Possible
values: {true, false}

--default-base-qualities 
Assign a default base quality  Default value: -1.

--deletions-default-quality 
default quality for the base deletions covariate  Default value: 45.

--disable-bam-index-caching,-DBIC 
If true, don't cache bam indexes, this will reduce memory requirements but may harm
performance if many intervals are specified.  Caching is automatically disabled if there
are no intervals specified.  Default value: false. Possible values: {true, false}

--disable-read-filter,-DF 
Read filters to be disabled before analysis  This argument may be specified 0 or more
times. Default value: null. Possible values: {MappedReadFilter,
MappingQualityAvailableReadFilter, MappingQualityNotZeroReadFilter,
NotDuplicateReadFilter, NotSecondaryAlignmentReadFilter,
PassesVendorQualityCheckReadFilter, WellformedReadFilter}

--disable-sequence-dictionary-validation 
If specified, do not check the sequence dictionaries from our inputs for compatibility.
Use at your own risk!  Default value: false. Possible values: {true, false}

--exclude-intervals,-XL 
One or more genomic intervals to exclude from processing  This argument may be specified 0
or more times. Default value: null.

--gatk-config-file    A configuration file to use with the GATK.  Default value: null.

--gcs-max-retries,-gcs-retries 
If the GCS bucket channel errors out, how many times it will attempt to re-initiate the
connection  Default value: 20.

--gcs-project-for-requester-pays 
Project to bill when accessing "requester pays" buckets. If unset, these buckets cannot be
accessed.  User must have storage.buckets.get permission on the bucket being accessed.
Default value: .

--help,-h            display the help message  Default value: false. Possible values: {true, false}

--indels-context-size,-ics 
Size of the k-mer context to be used for base insertions and deletions  Default value: 3.

--insertions-default-quality 
default quality for the base insertions covariate  Default value: 45.

--interval-exclusion-padding,-ixp 
Amount of padding (in bp) to add to each interval you are excluding.  Default value: 0.

--interval-merging-rule,-imr 
Interval merging rule for abutting intervals  Default value: ALL. Possible values: {ALL,
OVERLAPPING_ONLY}

--interval-padding,-ip 
Amount of padding (in bp) to add to each interval you are including.  Default value: 0.

--interval-set-rule,-isr 
Set merging approach to use for combining interval inputs  Default value: UNION. Possible
values: {UNION, INTERSECTION}

--intervals,-L        One or more genomic intervals over which to operate  This argument may be specified 0 or
more times. Default value: null.

--lenient,-LE        Lenient processing of VCF files  Default value: false. Possible values: {true, false}

--low-quality-tail      minimum quality for the bases in the tail of the reads to be considered  Default value: 2.

--max-variants-per-shard 
If non-zero, partitions VCF output into shards, each containing up to the given number of
records.  Default value: 0.

--maximum-cycle-value,-max-cycle 
The maximum cycle value permitted for the Cycle covariate  Default value: 500.

--mismatches-context-size,-mcs 
Size of the k-mer context to be used for base mismatches  Default value: 2.

--mismatches-default-quality 
default quality for the base mismatches covariate  Default value: -1.

--preserve-qscores-less-than 
Don't recalibrate bases with quality scores less than this threshold (with -bqsr)  Default
value: 6.

--quantizing-levels  number of distinct quality scores in the quantized output  Default value: 16.

--QUIET              Whether to suppress job-summary info on System.err.  Default value: false. Possible
values: {true, false}

--read-filter,-RF     Read filters to be applied before analysis  This argument may be specified 0 or more
times. Default value: null. Possible values: {AlignmentAgreesWithHeaderReadFilter,
AllowAllReadsReadFilter, AmbiguousBaseReadFilter, CigarContainsNoNOperator,
ExcessiveEndClippedReadFilter, FirstOfPairReadFilter,
FlowBasedTPAttributeSymetricReadFilter, FlowBasedTPAttributeValidReadFilter,
FragmentLengthReadFilter, GoodCigarReadFilter, HasReadGroupReadFilter,
HmerQualitySymetricReadFilter, IntervalOverlapReadFilter,
JexlExpressionReadTagValueFilter, LibraryReadFilter, MappedReadFilter,
MappingQualityAvailableReadFilter, MappingQualityNotZeroReadFilter,
MappingQualityReadFilter, MatchingBasesAndQualsReadFilter, MateDifferentStrandReadFilter,
MateDistantReadFilter, MateOnSameContigOrNoMappedMateReadFilter,
MateUnmappedAndUnmappedReadFilter, MetricsReadFilter,
NonChimericOriginalAlignmentReadFilter, NonZeroFragmentLengthReadFilter,
NonZeroReferenceLengthAlignmentReadFilter, NotDuplicateReadFilter,
NotOpticalDuplicateReadFilter, NotProperlyPairedReadFilter,
NotSecondaryAlignmentReadFilter, NotSupplementaryAlignmentReadFilter,
OverclippedReadFilter, PairedReadFilter, PassesVendorQualityCheckReadFilter,
PlatformReadFilter, PlatformUnitReadFilter, PrimaryLineReadFilter,
ProperlyPairedReadFilter, ReadGroupBlackListReadFilter, ReadGroupHasFlowOrderReadFilter,
ReadGroupReadFilter, ReadLengthEqualsCigarLengthReadFilter, ReadLengthReadFilter,
ReadNameReadFilter, ReadStrandFilter, ReadTagValueFilter, SampleReadFilter,
SecondOfPairReadFilter, SeqIsStoredReadFilter, SoftClippedReadFilter,
ValidAlignmentEndReadFilter, ValidAlignmentStartReadFilter, WellformedFlowBasedReadFilter,
WellformedReadFilter}

--read-index        Indices to use for the read inputs. If specified, an index must be provided for every read
input and in the same order as the read inputs. If this argument is not specified, the
path to the index for each input will be inferred automatically.  This argument may be
specified 0 or more times. Default value: null.

--read-validation-stringency,-VS 
Validation stringency for all SAM/BAM/CRAM/SRA files read by this program.  The default
stringency value SILENT can improve performance when processing a BAM file in which
variable-length data (read, qualities, tags) do not otherwise need to be decoded.  Default
value: SILENT. Possible values: {STRICT, LENIENT, SILENT}

--seconds-between-progress-updates 
Output traversal statistics every time this many seconds elapse  Default value: 10.0.

--sequence-dictionary 
Use the given sequence dictionary as the master/canonical sequence dictionary.  Must be a
.dict file.  Default value: null.

--sites-only-vcf-output 
If true, don't emit genotype fields when writing vcf file output.  Default value: false.
Possible values: {true, false}

--tmp-dir           Temp directory to use.  Default value: null.

--use-jdk-deflater,-jdk-deflater 
Whether to use the JdkDeflater (as opposed to IntelDeflater)  Default value: false.
Possible values: {true, false}

--use-jdk-inflater,-jdk-inflater 
Whether to use the JdkInflater (as opposed to IntelInflater)  Default value: false.
Possible values: {true, false}

--use-original-qualities,-OQ 
Use the base quality scores from the OQ tag  Default value: false. Possible values: {true,
false}

--verbosity         Control verbosity of logging.  Default value: INFO. Possible values: {ERROR, WARNING,
INFO, DEBUG}

--version            display the version number for this tool  Default value: false. Possible values: {true,
false}

Advanced Arguments:

--disable-tool-default-read-filters 
Disable all tool default read filters (WARNING: many tools will not function correctly
without their default read filters on)  Default value: false. Possible values: {true,
false}

--showHidden         display hidden arguments  Default value: false. Possible values: {true, false}

---

A USER ERROR has occurred: Argument known-sites was missing: Argument 'known-sites' is required

---

Set the system property GATK_STACKTRACE_ON_USER_EXCEPTION (--java-options '-DGATK_STACKTRACE_ON_USER_EXCEPTION=true') to print the stack trace.

Comment: This is not a Java programming question.  In fact, I don't think it is a programming question at all.  Rather ... it seems to be a question about how to >use< some software.  It is off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: And at a guess ... the error means that you have to add a "--known-sites" argument on the command line.  The error message says that argument is missing, and the command summary says it is a "Required" argument.

Comment: And I bet that `${Known_Sites}` is expanding to nothing ... because someone / something didn't set that environment variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please pay attention to this

> Using GATK jar /home/hi/Documents/gatk-4.4.0.0/gatk-package-4.4.0.0-local.jar Running: java -Dsamjdk.use_async_io_read_samtools=false -Dsamjdk.use_async_io_write_samtools=true -Dsamjdk.use_async_io_write_tribble=false -Dsamjdk.compression_level=2 -jar /home/hi/Documents/gatk-4.4.0.0/gatk-package-4.4.0.0-local.jar BaseRecalibrator -I /file_copy_sorted.bam -R *--known-sites* -O /sorted_Read1.table USAGE: BaseRecalibrator [arguments]

that is how GATK explains your command, as Stephen C said, ${Known_Sites}, which is a shell variable, may not be set before your running this command.

For hunman, your can provide dbSNP like `dbsnp_138.hg38.vcf.gz` and `Mills_and_1000G_gold_standard.indels.hg38.vcf` etc to `--known-sites` argument. If you can not find a known site for your data, please follow the [instructions](https://gatk.broadinstitute.org/hc/en-us/articles/360035890531-Base-Quality-Score-Recalibration-BQSR-) here.

Comment: Thank you for the help. 
with the given known site data was different from what I used. I used these known sites and it resolved the issue.

Comment: Then I get an error as "USER ERROR has occurred: Cannot read file:///home/hi/Documents/data/ref/Mills_and_1000G_gold_standard.indels.hg38.vcf because no suitable codecs found"

Comment: @user22752471, you can find a tool called `IndexFeatureFile` in GATK's Tool Index. Index the vcf file before running BQSR, or you can just download the index of the vcf file, Broad Institute has provided it, you can find it [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/genomics-public-data/resources/broad/hg38/v0/).  The index of a vcf file should ends with `.vcf.gz.tbi` or `vcf.idx`

Comment: Is there a way to get the correct vcf file? I have used "wget https://storage.googleapis.com/genomics-public-data/resources/broad/hg38/v0/Homo_sapiens_assembly38.dbsnp138.vcf" and Homo_sapiens_assembly38.dbsnp138.vcf.idx"  but still getting the error A USER ERROR has occurred: Cannot read file:///home/hi/Documents/data/ref/Homo_sapiens_assembly38.dbsnp138.vcf because no suitable codecs found 
Set the system property GATK_STACKTRACE_ON_USER_EXCEPTION (--java-options '-DGATK_STACKTRACE_ON_USER_EXCEPTION=true') to print the stack trace."

Comment: @user22752471 using `wget` to download a storaged in google was a good idea, to use `wget`, you should have the Direct Link, or using [`gsutil`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil)

Comment: Thank you for your support. I got the file